# How to use python apriori resolve the house voting binary dataset?

Tags: python, apriori

I want to use apriori to analysis house voting 84 dataset. There are total 17 column, the fist one is the "party" which are two categorical data. The rest columns are binary dataset. How t apply apriori in python the resolve it? The minsup= 0.3 and minconfidence= 0.9

[enter image description here][1]

These are my code: The output looks ugly and not reasonable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os  

from apyori import apriori 
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from efficient_apriori import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder

df = pd.read_table("house-votes-84.data", sep=",", header=None, 
na_values="?")
col_names = ['party', 'infants', 'water', 'budget', 'physician', 
'salvador','religious', 'satellite', 'aid', 'missile', 'immigration', 
'synfuels','education', 'superfund', 'crime', 'duty_free_exports', 
'eaa_rsa']
df = df.fillna(0)
df.columns = col_names
df.shape
print(df.head())

df = df.replace({'y': 1, 'n': -1, '?': 0})
print(df.head()) 

records = []  
for i in range(0, 435):  
records.append([str(df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0, 16)])

association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.3, min_confidence=0.9)  
association_results = list(association_rules) 
print(len(association_rules)) 
print(association_rules[0])  `enter code here
```

OUTPUT:

{1: {('-1',): 433, ('0',): 154, ('1',): 434, ('democrat',): 267, ('republican',): 168}, 2: {('-1', '0'): 152, ('-1', '1'): 433, ('-1', 'democrat'): 266, ('-1', 'republican'): 167, ('0', '1'): 153, ('1', 'democrat'): 267, ('1', 'republican'): 167}, 3: {('-1', '0', '1'): 152, ('-1', '1', 'democrat'): 266, ('-1', '1', 'republican'): 167}}

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Do you have a minimal code ?

Comment: This is the code I learned from other websites, but it seems not work.from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori apriori(df, min_support=0.3， use_colnames=True)

Answer (score 0):

The `apriori` function from `efficient_apriori` returns a tuple `(itemsets, rules)`. To use `efficient_apriori`, you can do something like:

```py
from efficient_apriori import apriori
itemsets, rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.3, min_confidence=0.9)
for rule in rules:
    print(rule)
```

For more information, see this [example](https://github.com/tommyod/Efficient-Apriori#example).